# VuesJS components template

Tags: vue.js, components

I'm a VueJS beginner and i'm struggling to understand some component logic.

If i have my component (simplified for clarity) :

```
Vue.component('nav-bar', {
        template: '<nav [some code] ></nav>'
}
```

This component represent the whole navigation bar of my page.
In my HTML file, how can i insert code inside the component?

Something like:

```
<nav-bar>
    <button></button>
    ...
</nav-bar>
```

Could you please tell me if it is the right way to do it?

Comment: for this you have to use slots, try to check the related documentation:
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least three options I can think of:

- Using [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref), or
- Slot props with [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots), or
- [`provide`/`inject`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject).

---

#### 1. Example with `ref`

```js
Vue.component('NavBar', {
  template: `
    <nav>
      <slot></slot>
    </nav>
  `,

  methods: {
    run() {
      console.log('Parent\'s method invoked.');
    }
  }
});

new Vue().$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <nav-bar ref="navbar">
    <button @click="$refs.navbar.run()">Run with refs</button>
  </nav-bar>
</div>
```

#### 2. With Scoped `<slot>`

```js
Vue.component('NavBar', {
  template: `
    <nav>
      <slot v-bind="$options.methods"></slot>
    </nav>
  `,

  methods: {
    run() {
      console.log('Parent\'s method invoked.');
    }
  }
});

new Vue().$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <nav-bar>
    <template #default="methods">
      <button @click="methods.run">Run with slot props</button>
    </template>
  </nav-bar>
</div>
```

#### 3. With `provide` and `inject`

```js
Vue.component('NavBar', {
  template: `
    <nav>
      <slot></slot>
    </nav>
  `,
  
  provide() {
    const props = {
      ...this.$options.methods,

      // The rest of props you'd like passed down to the child components.
    };

    return props;
  },

  methods: {
    run() {
      console.log('Parent\'s method invoked.');
    }
  }
});

// In order to "receive" or `inject` the parent props,
// the child(ren) needs to be a component itself.
Vue.component('Child', {
  template: `
    <button @click="run">
      <slot></slot>
    </button>
  `,

  // Inject anything `provided` by the direct parent
  // This could also be `data` or `props`, etc.
  inject: ['run']
});

new Vue().$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <nav-bar>
    <template>
      <child>Run with injected method</child>
    </template>
  </nav-bar>
</div>
```